# How to call UINavigation controller  in objective c

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, animation

I am trying to implement facebook like sliding view without using any framework. What i am doing was i created UINavigation Controller view (say NVC1) in app delegate and i loaded a table view in it. I am also creating another navigationviewcontroller (say NVC2) on top NVC1. i placed a bar button item at the top left of NVC2. when i click on the bar button in NVC2, it will slide to side of the screen (i am animating manually), so that it will reveal the NVC1 that is behind NVC2. As already said NVC1 contains table view. If i click the table view cell in NVC2, it should show/animate over NVC1. How can i do that or is there any way to do that.

[image: NVC1]

[image: NVC2]

Answer (score 0):

If you're using iOS 5, use storyboarding, create a nav controller, add your VC with tableView, create a second VC then right-click-drag from the 1st VC's tableView's cell to the 2nd VC & select "push". It will then all happen automagically! Sounds convoluted, but once you've done it a couple of times it's so much easier than messing around with code. On the other hand, sometimes you need to code it - if you really need to & you're still stuck, let me know & I'll post some code for you.

Comment: :i am not using ios5. Also i am not interested in using xib . i am creating all by programmatically..

Comment: how can i call navigation controller from another view.. when i use pushViewController, new NVC2 view controller is coming.the old NVC2 (that i animated) is still there.. how can i animate NVC2 From NVC1.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the method `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`  and write  `SecondViewControllerNVC2 *objectNVC2` in .h file

it's look like following

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {       
                if (!objectNVC2) {
                objectNVC2 = [[SecondViewControllerNVC2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewControllerNVC2" bundle:nil];
              UIBarButtonItem *backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
            self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backBarButtonItem;
            [backBarButtonItem release];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:objectNVC2 animated:YES];     
}
```

Comment: the above code will push the new NVC2 to the screen. But the NVC2 that i already slided to the right remains there...